# javaClass in kotlin return unexpected type

Tags: kotlin

I wanted to know the underlying java class for this

```
    val x: Array<Int> = arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    val y: List<Int> = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    println(x.javaClass)
    println(y.javaClass)
```

The output is

> class [Ljava.lang.Integer;
>
> class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList

Can someone point out what is `[Ljava.lang.Integer` Am i missing something?

Comment: That's what `toString` returns for `Class<Integer[]>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a valid string representation of the type of `Integer[]`. You are actually calling implicit `toString()` by `println()`, which calls `getName()`. You can find the documentation of this naming scheme here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName()